# These mathematical expressions are showing Undefined control sequence error

Tags: math-mode, equations

The following two equations are throwing error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[center]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}    
% Math packages
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% Graphics package
\usepackage{graphicx}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\bfseries}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\title{Some title}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
$Activeness=\begin{cases}0.9 & Energy > 75\% \\0.7 & Energy=50\%-74\%\\0.3 & Otherwise \end{cases}$\\
$Link~stability=\begin{cases}0.35-0.45 & \text{single node}\\0.15-0.34 & \text{two nodes}\\otherwise & \text{every adjacent node} \end{cases}$
 \end{document}
```

Besides the suggestion to the above problem, any suggestion to display these equations in a better way will be very helpful in elevating my knowledge. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does `\theadfont` come from? And where does `\gt` come from?

Comment: Why are there many `~`? You can use `\text{} `or `\textup{}`.

Comment: \theadfont is being used in one of my tables. Is it possible to keep it like that? I have replaced \gt with >.

Comment: @Sebastiano I have put them inside \text{}

Comment: Your error is coming from `\theadfont`.  It needs to be defined by a package.  Without `\text` or `\textup`, `Activeness` is being typeset as if it were the product of 10 different variables, one for each letter.

Comment: so if I put every word in the equation in \text{ }, will it solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you get is due to `\theadfont` not being defined in the first place. It would if you load `makecell`.

Just remove the faulty line.

On the other hand, the output you get is not very pretty.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

This should be a display, rather than two single equations
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Activeness}
&= \begin{cases}
   0.9 & \mathrm{Energy} \ge 75\% \\
   0.7 & 50\% \le \mathrm{Energy} < 75\% \\
   0.3 & \text{Otherwise}
   \end{cases}
\\
\mathrm{Link\ stability}
&= \begin{cases}
   0.35\text{--}0.45 & \text{single node} \\
   0.15\text{--}0.34 & \text{two nodes}\\
   \text{otherwise}  & \text{every adjacent node}
   \end{cases}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am a bit surprised at the mixing of `\text` and `\mathrm`. What is your mental process deciding which to use for which?

Comment: @WillieWong “Activeness”, “Energy” and the others with `\mathrm` are mathematical variables, “otherwise” is text.

Comment: I guess I was confused by Link Stability. I personally would not choose a two-word phrase as a variable name.